The volume of a cone
I am trying to derive the volume of cone without pouring liquid from the cone into the cylinder three times.
I was thinking of rotating a right-angled triangle with base $r$ and height $h$ by $360^{\circ}$ to form a cone. The area of the triangle is $\frac{bh}2=\frac{rh}2$, and if I rotate it $360^{\circ}$, wouldn't it give me the volume of the cone, which according to me should be $\frac12\times r\times h\times2\pi$, since $360^{\circ}$) is $2\pi$ radians?
Please don't use calculus or any advance mathematics, I am too young for that.
Thank you!

Your result of multiplying by $2\pi$ follows from the circumference of a circle of radius $r$, which would've made sense if you extended the argument to the surface area of a cone. I don't understand how it applies to its volume.

I don't think you can compute the volume of a cone without calculus. In a nutshell, the gist of using calculus here is that the area of a circle formed by rotating a line segment about one of its end points is $\pi l^2$ where $l$ is the length of the line segment. The same thinking can be applied to rotating a $2D$ shape about an axis on it if we consider it to be comprised of line segments of very small width.

Also, if you see the formula you believe should be the volume of a cone, it has the dimensions of area, not volume.

Are you allowed to use the volume of a triangular pyramid?

Related https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1091817/92915

Since we should not use calculus here, I would like to show how physicists may approach such a problem.
I would like to state, without further proof,

that a pyramid and a cone would have exactly the same volume if they have the same base area and same height. (from Cavalieri's principle)

that a pyramid would have its volume proportional to height and base area. So $V=CSh$ where we need to find $C$.


Now we consider a pyramid with base area $S$ and height $h$ and cut it at $\frac{2}{3}h$, by proportionality the cross-section area would be $\frac{1}{9}S$:

Let $V_1$, $V_2$, $V_3$ be the volume of the lower pieces as shown, and $V_0$ be the volume of the top piece. We may easily deduce
$V_1=\frac{2}{27}Sh$
$V_2=\frac{1}{2}V_1=\frac{1}{27}Sh$
$V_3=C\frac{2}{27}Sh$
$V_0=C\frac{1}{27}Sh$
so
$V_1+4V_2+4V_3+V_0=CSh$
$\frac{2}{9}+\frac{1}{3}C=C$
$C=\frac{1}{3}$
which is the desired result.

If you accept the $c \times \text{ base area } \times \text{ perpendicular height }$ works for cones and pyramids etc. all with the same $c$, then perhaps the easiest way is to split a cube into pyramids.  For example with base $ABCD$ and other vertex $G$, with base $AEFB$ and other vertex $G$, and with base $ADHE$ and other vertex $G$.  There are three congruent pyramids summing to the cube so $c=\frac13$.

If you want to skip calculus, use the second Pappus's theorem (see Wikipedia: Pappus's centroid theorem), which is based on integration hidden behind scenes.
It requires you to calculate the position of triangle's centroid, specifically its distance from the axis of revolution.
You may also use the Cavalieri's principle (Wiki), which provides a method of integration in disguise.

Let's approximate the cone as a stack of cylindrical disks, as in a wedding cake, or a Tower of Hanoi puzzle.

Divide the height of the cone into $n$ equal-thickness discs.  That is, each disc is $\frac{h}{n}$ units thick.
Now, consider the cross-section of the cone: A right triangle with its right angle at the origin and its other two vertices at the points $(r, 0)$ and $(0, h)$.  Its hypotenuse has the equation $y = h - \frac{h}{r}x$, or $x = r - \frac{r}{h}y$.
Index the discs by $k = 1$ to $n$, starting at the bottom.  The top of disc $k$ has $y = \frac{hk}{n}$, at which the cone has a radius of $x = r - \frac{kr}{n}$.  The bottom of disc $k$ has $y = \frac{h(k-1)}{n}$, at which the cone has a radius of $x = r - \frac{kr}{n} + \frac{r}{n}$.
To build our stacked-disc approximation of the cone, let's arbitrary choose the midpoint of the cone slice for the radius of each disc.  That is, disc $k$ has a radius of $r - \frac{kr}{n} + \frac{r}{2n}$.  Since the volume of a cylinder is $V = \pi r^2 h$, the total volume of the stack of discs is:
$$V = \sum_{k=1}^n \pi \left(r - \frac{kr}{n} + \frac{r}{2n}\right)^2 \frac{h}{n}$$
$$= \frac{\pi h}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{2nr - 2kr + r}{2n}\right)^2$$
$$= \frac{\pi h}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{4n^2r^2 - 4knr^2 + 2nr^2 - 4knr^2 + 4k^2r^2 - 2kr^2 + 2nr^2 - 2kr^2 + r^2}{4n^2}$$
$$= \frac{\pi h}{4n^3} \sum_{k=1}^n (4r^2k^2 - (8n + 4)r^2k + (4n^2 + 4n + 1)r^2)$$
$$= \frac{\pi hr^2}{n^3} \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 - \frac{\pi h(2n + 1)r^2}{n^3} \sum_{k=1}^n k + \frac{\pi h(4n^2 + 4n + 1)r^2}{4n^3} \sum_{k=1}^n 1$$
To simplify this expression, use the summation formulas:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n 1 = n , \sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} , \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6}$$
So:
$$V = \frac{\pi hr^2}{n^3} \frac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6} - \frac{\pi h(2n + 1)r^2}{n^3}\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + \frac{\pi h(4n^2 + 4n + 1)r^2}{4n^3} n$$
$$\frac{12n^2V}{\pi h r^2(2n + 1)} = -4(n + 1) + 3(2n + 1) = 2n - 1$$
$$V = \frac{(2n + 1)(2n - 1)\pi r^2 h}{12n^2} = \frac{(4n^2 - 1)\pi r^2 h}{12n^2}$$
$$\boxed{V = \frac{\pi r^2 h}{3} - \frac{\pi r^2 h}{12n^2}}$$
To obtain a more accurate approximation for the volume of the cone, we can use higher values for $n$, slicing the cone into thinner and thinner discs.  For sufficiently large $n$, the contribution of the $-\frac{\pi r^2 h}{12n^2}$ term becomes negligible, and thus we can say:
$$\boxed{V = \frac{\pi r^2 h}{3}}$$
This approach is, in fact, very similar to how the volume of a cone can be derived using calculus.  Using a “limit” or “definite integral” in this context is just a formalization of using infinitesimally thin discs.

That one is easier to understand by a slight generalization. We may infer that we must have the volume $V = (A+B+\sqrt{AB})h/3$ for an amputated cone of height $h$ bounded with surface areas $A$ and $B$ from the following considerations. When $A=B$ this formula correctly reduces to the volume of a cylinder $V = Ah$. When $A$ and $B$ are exchanged the volume stays the same. When $A$ and $B$ are doubled, while $h$ is held fixed, the volume is doubled. When we put two such amputated cones on top of each other to form one bigger amputated cone, one can check that the formula gets consistent and in fact this is one way to prove its correctness. For example if we have two such amputated cones, each of height $h$, and connected on the middle surface of area $B$ with top and bottom areas $A$ and $C$, then the middle surface has the average area of $A$ and $C$ where the average shall be computed as $B = (\frac{\sqrt{A}+\sqrt{C}}{2})^2$ and then, by using this, one may check that $h(A+B+\sqrt{AB}) + h(B + C + \sqrt{BC}) = 2h (A+C + \sqrt{AC})$, which basically proves the formula. When $A=0$ we get a cone with the volume $V = Bh/3$.

You seem to suggest that the volume should be
$$\frac 12 . r.h. 2\pi r $$
The constant 1 used by you implicitly in two dimensions does not hold for three dimensions. Neither does the distance of maximum radius $r$ swept out holds that way. To obtain a correct result the procedure adopted should be also correct.
In science, you can proceed from a generality to a particular situation but not the other way round.
One useful procedure to obtain volumes without integration/calculus is by the application of the Pappu's theorem. It states that the cross section area is to be multiplied by the length traversed by the center of gravity to find volume.

Here the circumference is obtained from the red radius from triangle property as
$$ 2 \pi \frac {r}{3} = \frac23 \pi r  $$
and volume is
$$ \frac12 \cdot r\cdot h \cdot \frac23 \pi r = \frac13 \pi r^2 h $$
