# On the volume of a cone?

Tags: geometry, definite-integrals, solid-of-revolution

We determine the area of the rectangle triangle (which is $\frac{rh}{2}$, $r$ is the radius of circle and $h$ the height). Then we can think that the volume of the cone is the area of the rectangle which runs the interval $[0,2\pi]$. Where is the mistake ? (Maybe it is the question of the "basis" considered)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860071/why-isnt-the-volume-formula-for-a-cone-pi-r2h

Comment: Ok... Why is there a downvote...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can obtain the result following that idea by [**Pappus's centroid theorem**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PappussCentroidTheorem.html)

[image]

notably, since for the cone the centroid of the generating triangle is located at $\frac13 r$ from the rotation axis we have

$$V=2\pi\frac13 r\cdot \frac12 rh=\pi r^2\frac h 3$$

Comment: Thanks ! Do you have references/books with this kind of things ?

Comment: @Maman I suggest to take a look on the resources you can find on the web, as for example here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PappussCentroidTheorem.html https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/